# Exporting List nested lists with custom objects to csv not working

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell code:

```
$data = @{};
// code to populate data, sample:
$listData = New-Object System.Collection.Generic.List[object];
$listData.Add([PSCustomObject]@{Id = 1, Name = "Employee1"});
$data.Add("KEY1", $listData);

$data.Values | Export-Csv -Path "path of file"
```

The result is not as expected, I get information about the the list Capacity, count, if readonly....

Comment: Csv is 2D and you're feeding a multidimensional object, how should it handle it? Use Json or XML to handle this type of object.

Comment: Can you show us what you're seeing vs what you want to see?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon: Thanks. I created another generic list where I pushed all collections there and exported it.

Answer (score 0):

There were two typos in the question, but the basic idea works fine:

```
$data = @{}
$listData = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object]
                                       #^ missing s
$listData.Add([PSCustomObject]@{Id = 1; Name = "Employee1"})
                                     #^ hash tables are semicolon-separated
$data.Add("KEY1", $listData)
$data.Values | Export-Csv -Path "path of file"

# outputs:
Id Name     
-- ----     
 1 Employee1
```